# Using np.mean() in Python

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I want to calculate the arithmetic mean of a column using `np.mean` from the numpy libary.

Let's say I have different dogs in the rows and their health properties in the columns. Now I want to calculate the mean of column 8, which includes the heart rate.

What I already did:

```
import numpy as np

def mean_heart_rate(D):
    # [HERE I'LL NEED TO ADD np.mean()]
    mhr = np.mean(a)
    return mhr
```

What do I need to do? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
values_of_col_8 = df.col["name_col_8"].values
np.mean(values_of_col_8)
```

Questions :

- In which format are your columns ? Pandas ? list ?
- why don't you stick to "np" rather than "no" for naming numpy ?

EDIT :

- if your structure is a list of list :

  values_of_col_8 = [row[7] for row in values]

(we take col 7 because arrays are indexed by 0)

Comment: ''No'' seems to be a typo

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how professionals call this, I guess it is a 2D table. I corrected it to np, it was just a typo. What do I need to replace ["name_col_8"] with? With "mean_heart_rate"?

Comment: Now I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btsLh.png It still doesn't seem to output the correct value.